# How select data from two table with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying for join of two tables receipt and sale. but i dont get thse result.I want to get result between two date intervel

My sale table structure

```
id       date             total

26       2014-07-16       9000
27       2014-07-15       6000
```

Receipt table structure

```
id      date                nettotal

18      2014-07-16          1000
19      2014-07-15          2500
```

I want to get the result like

```
date             total      nettotal

2014-07-16       9000
2014-07-16                  1000
2014-07-15       6000
2014-07-15                  2500
```

Any body know these select query for get these result?

Comment: And what have you already tried?

Comment: I suggest you [read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: alredy tried with unio ,but i sont get these result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date, total, nettotal
from (select date, total, null as nettotal, 2 as sort_col
from sale
union all
select date null as total, nettotal, 1 as sort_col
from receipt) as a
order by date desc, sort_col desc
```

**Note:** You need to show what you've tried

Comment: Thanks,it is working .I want to select data between two 2 dates.Where i put where clause in these query?

Comment: You can figure out that... don't ask for a full solution, take the time to think, take the time to understand, and take the time to try to help yourself. That's the reason I put that final remark in my answer

Comment: Hi friend,can you help me ?i want to add limit in these query..Where i put limit in these query?